How to send push notifications to iOS from AWS Pinpoint?
I'm trying to send push notifications from AWS Pinpoint. For years up until recently Pinpoint was able to connect to Firebase Cloud Messaging and send messages to both iOS (multiple bundle IDs) and Android, but iOS has stopped working for an unknown reason. The iOS messages used to send from AWS Pinpoint -> Firebase -> APN -> Device.  I say this because the Push Notification settings for AWS Pinpoint had only Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) set up with Token Credentials.  No configurations for Apple Push Notification service (APNs) were setup. As far as I understand, this means Pinpoint wasn't using APN to send messages to iOS apps directly.
I performed three tests.

First, I used the "Test Messaging" service of AWS Pinpoint to send messages to newly generated FCNs, or device tokens (still without the APN settings). Both Android and iOS resulted in:


Message sent
Successfully sent push message.

However, only Android actually received the push notifications.  iOS did not receive anything even though no error occurred.

Second, I set up a campaign in the "Messaging" section in the Firebase console to test sending push notifications. All of the Bundle ID's registered in Apple App Configuration of Cloud Messaging settings successfully received the notifications (the notifications actually showed on apps). This proves that the APNs Authentication Keys for all the Bundle IDs are correct and the connection between the iOS apps and Firebase is properly set up.

Finally, I went back to AWS Pinpoint to set up the APN settings for iOS with the same Key ID, Bundle Identifier, Team Identifier, and the Authentication Key (the .p8 file) used in Firebase, thinking maybe sending notifications directly to apps bypassing Firebase might work. But, when executed a test in "Test Messaging", no notifications showed on apps even though AWS console showed "Successfully sent push message."



Have you come to a solution for this? I think I am in the same situation.
